# Ms sql server, backup and bring it local from aws rds ms sql server database

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, backup, rds

we need make regular backup and bring it localy for auditing porpouse.
How we can have ms sql server backup from an aws rds ms sql server database ?
Any automatic way to do it?

Comment: nothing because before start with rds I need know if this is possible and if easy task otherwise we need to think to use it..

Answer (score 0):

**NO** – AWS RDS does not give a direct/automatic option of creating a .bak file which you can get in to your local system and audit.

**YES** – There are ways to do this. If your database is :

*small* – Generate script from SSMS, with all schema and data. this will create a .sql file, then zip it, and get it locally for you.

*large* -- use `bcp` command to export data from the database

Comment: what is bcp ? any link / documentation ?